# What could prevent me from renaming a file locked?

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-permissions

I've run into a very weird issue on a build server where it won't let me rename any file 'locked' on the entire D drive as it throws a permissions error.

I have local admin rights which allow me to rename a file locked on the C drive and rename a file on the D drive to any other name. This affects all directories and extensions.

Comment: Do you literally mean that you can't change a file's name to be the word `locked` ?

Comment: Yes that's what I literally mean, turned out IT had blocked creating files called locked via group policy in an attempt to prevent the spread of crypto lockers

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that IT had put in place restrictions on creating files called 'locked' via group policy to attempt to prevent the spread of crypto lockers.